# java eclipse- fileReader throws FileNotFoundException though <file>.exists() returns true

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

when i attempt to create a BufferedReader using a text file in my workspace the FileReader in the "new bufferedreader statement throws a filenotfoundexception. yet .exists() and .canRead() both return true for the file

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File fighter0 = new File("resources/fighter0.txt");
    //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fighter0));
    System.out.println(fighter0.exists());
    System.out.println(fighter0.canRead());
}
```

here's the code

```
true
true
```

and the output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

at main.Core.main(Core.java:21)
```

and the exception that's thrown when i uncomment the bufferedreader line

i found a closed thread similar to this one, but couldn't find any clear answer in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compiler error, not a runtime failure:

> Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

The compiler is stating that that exception must be caught by the client code. It can be corrected by implementing a `try/catch` around the use of `FileReader` or by stating that `main()` `throws FileNotFoundException`.

Research checked and unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is compilation error. It says that you have not handled the `FileNotFoundException` exception.
Try `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception`

Comment: i tried your suggestion and the error stopped showing up. does that mean i can read the file with the bufferedreader now?

Comment: Yes. As @hmjd said Research checked and unchecked exceptions